# Could you please tell me why I am receiving just the * as an output and not the string entered initially, as the decrypted string?

Tags: python, encryption

**Question**

**Write a program that inputs a main string and then creates an
encrypted string by embedding a short symbol based string after each character.
The program should be also able to produce the decrypted string from
encrypted string.**

**Code**

```
def encrypt(string,key):
    return key.join(string)
def decrypt(string,key):
    return key.split(string)
#main
original_str=input("Enter a string:")
encrypt_key=input("Enter encryption key:")

encrypt_str=encrypt(original_str,encrypt_key)
print("The encrypted string:",encrypt_str)

decrypt_str=decrypt(encrypt_str,encrypt_key)
decrypted_str=" ".join(decrypt_str)
print("The decrypted string:",decrypted_str)
```

**Output**

```
Enter a string:twinkle twinkle little star
Enter encryption key:*
The encrypted string: t*w*i*n*k*l*e* *t*w*i*n*k*l*e* *l*i*t*t*l*e* *s*t*a*r
The decrypted string: *
```

Issue

I want the output of the decrypted string to be:

twinkle twinkle little star

and not *

Comment: `return key.split(string)` This should be `return string.split(key)`.

Comment: As a minor note, your "encryption" program is not 100% correct.  It says to add the key after every character.  You are not adding the key after the last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `decrypt` function with this:

```py
def decrypt(string,key):
   return string.split(key)
```

And also replace `decrypted_str = " ".join(decrypt_str)` with `decrypted_str = "".join(decrypt_str)` (the difference is the space).